# Where does GitLab execute its environment job?

Tags: environment, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm looking over the [docs on environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html). I'm trying to understand what these statements actually mean in terms of what server executes the script.

> Environments are like tags for your CI jobs, describing where code gets deployed.
>
> The environment keyword is just a hint for GitLab that this job actually deploys to this environment's name.

It makes use of non-difinitive terms 'like' and 'hint' so does it actually execute on Runners tagged with the environment name?

It also states:

> If you have a deployment service such as Kubernetes enabled for your project, you can use it to assist with your deployments

Is that a requirement to utilize environments or just a helpful manager?

And I guess my final question would be, if I have multiple runners tagged with an environment (assuming that is how it works) would the job execute on all runners unlike tags which just choose any runner that matches?

Answer (score 1):

The environment name has no effect on the execution location, it is used for display purposes in the Environment UI.

Tags are still specified on the deployment step to determine where execution is run. This does not require Kubernetes to use, but I suspect that functionality with environment management is greatly reduced.